# Most efficient way to implement table with multiple column?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am attempting to create a table with multiple column such as

[image]

The initial implementation I thought was is that use 
**Hashtable** with key being "String" and value being "List" of String.
But is this the most efficient way? I would be accessing data entry a lot and I am assuming since Java List is implemented in ArrayList, updating each data entry is not too slow. Am I correct?

Comment: Add more elaborate example. Is the number of cols fixed? And remote Thanks from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Guava's [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

For instance using a [`HashBasedTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html):

```
Table<RowType, ColumnType, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();
```

Comment: Would this be much faster than what I was thinking of implementing?

Comment: Yes, it uses HashMap for both rows and columns.